# When processing and displaying the colors the application is hanging for half of second , maybe a bit less , is there a way to avoid from being delay?

Tags: c#, winforms

This method display the colors:

The variable extractedColors is List

```
private void DrawExtractedColorsProgressively(Graphics g, Rectangle circleRect)
{
    if (extractedColors.Count > 0)
    {
        float angle = 360f / extractedColors.Count;

        for (int i = 0; i < extractedColors.Count; i++)
        {
            using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(extractedColors[i]))
            {
                float startAngle = i * angle;
                g.FillPie(brush, circleRect, startAngle, angle);
            }

            // Update the progress bar
            UpdateProgressBar(i, extractedColors.Count);
        }
    }
}
```

then inside the paint event:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);

    int borderWidth = 2; // Border width
    Rectangle borderRect = new Rectangle(borderWidth, borderWidth, Width - 2 * borderWidth, Height - 2 * borderWidth);
    Pen p = new Pen(Color.Red, borderWidth);

    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

    // Draw the circular red border
    e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(p, borderRect);

    if (displayedImage != null)
    {
        // Create a circular region to clip the image
        GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
        path.AddEllipse(borderRect);
        Region region = new Region(path);
        e.Graphics.Clip = region;

        // Draw the clipped image
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(displayedImage, borderRect);

        // Reset the clip region
        e.Graphics.ResetClip();
    }

    // Draw extracted colors inside the circle progressively
    DrawExtractedColorsProgressively(e.Graphics, borderRect);
}
```

This method create the colors :

```
private async Task<List<Color>> ExtractUniqueColorsAsync(Image image)
{
    List<Color> uniqueColors = new List<Color>();

    if (image != null)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(image);
        int width = bitmap.Width;
        int height = bitmap.Height;

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
        BitmapData bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        int totalPixels = width * height;
        int processedPixels = 0;

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            unsafe
            {
                byte* ptr = (byte*)bitmapData.Scan0;

                for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                    {
                        int offset = y * bitmapData.Stride + x * 4;
                        byte blue = ptr[offset];
                        byte green = ptr[offset + 1];
                        byte red = ptr[offset + 2];
                        byte alpha = ptr[offset + 3];

                        Color pixelColor = Color.FromArgb(alpha, red, green, blue);

                        if (!uniqueColors.Contains(pixelColor))
                        {
                            uniqueColors.Add(pixelColor);
                        }

                        processedPixels++;

                        int progressPercentage = (int)((double)processedPixels / totalPixels * 100);
                        ProgressChanged?.Invoke(progressPercentage);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
    }

    return uniqueColors;
}
```

and last updating the progressBar

```
private void UpdateProgressBar(int currentColorIndex, int totalColors)
{
    if (progressBar != null)
    {
        int progressPercentage = (int)((double)(currentColorIndex + 1) / totalColors * 100);
        progressBar.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            progressBar.Value = progressPercentage;
        });
    }
}
```

the class code is much bigger I tried to cut off some of the code, but these parts are all connected.

the delay is when it's start making the process of the code in the method:  DrawExtractedColorsProgressively

what I'm trying to do is one process progress for all the operations so it will look like one smooth process. I make first the code in the method ExtractUniqueColorsAsync and then in the method DrawExtractedColorsProgressively but make them like one whole process and not with the delay in the middle.

Comment: It's not clear what calls `ExtractUniqueColorsAsync()` and when it's called. `ProgressChanged` looks like an `Action<int>`, also not clear what uses it. Less clear is the reason why you have `DrawExtractedColorsProgressively()` inside the `OnPaint()` override of whatever Control that is. Thats method is called each time the Control is painted. Very expensive. Even less clear is why `UpdateProgressBar()` is calling `progressBar.Invoke()`, given that method is called from the UI Thread. Synchronous invocation in the same Thread is as bad as it gets (the reason why `InvokeRequired` exists)

Comment: ... but, why invoking? Did you remove pieces of code that use this method cross-thread? An orphaned earlier attempt? Or is it actually like that? -- Remove `DrawExtractedColorsProgressively()` from `OnPaint()` to begin with -- Side note: `GraphicsPath` is disposable, as the `Region` object. You cannot leave the latter undisposed in any case, ever

Answer (score 0):

If a 1932 x 2575 image is being processed in your `ExtractUniqueColorsAsync` method, it means you're going to do this close to 5 million times (on a list that might have ~5 million other values).

```
if (!uniqueColors.Contains(pixelColor)) ...
```

You may not need a `ProgressBar` at all if you use an indexed collection of some kind. When I tested this, it seemed to run ~2 orders of magnitude faster.

```
    Dictionary<Color, int> uniqueColors = new Dictionary<Color, int>();
    // Task.Run for each X x Y...
    {...
#if true
    // Takes ~ 1 second for 1932 x 2576
    if(uniqueColors.TryGetValue(pixelColor, out int value))
    {
        uniqueColors[pixelColor] = value + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        uniqueColors[pixelColor] = 1;
    }
    var progressPreview = Convert.ToInt32((double)(y * width + x) / (width * height) * 100);
    // Send only when integer changes.
    if (progressPreview != _prevProgress)
    {
        ProgressChanged?.Invoke(
            this,
            new ProgressChangedEventArgs(
                progressPreview, stopwatch.Elapsed));
        _prevProgress = progressPreview;
    }
#else
    // Takes ~ 2 minutes for 1932 x 2576
    if (!benchmarkList.Contains(pixelColor))
    {
        benchmarkList.Add(pixelColor);
        ProgressChanged?.Invoke(
            this,
            new ProgressChangedEventArgs(
                Convert.ToInt32((double)(y * width + x) / (width * height) * 100), UniqueColors.ToArray()));
    }
#endif
```

You're also sending (again, worst case) 5 Million `ProgressChanged` events for a `ProgressBar` with (probably) 100 increments. It seems reasonable to throttle that down and send the notification only when the integer value of progress changes.

---

**Progress during extraction**
[image: extraction]

**Drawing the pie chart progressively**

[image: time lapse images]

When you go to draw the pie chart, your objective seems to be adding the colors "one-by-one" which takes several seconds by design. Consider making a critical section to prevent reentrancy, however.

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);
    int borderWidth = 2;
    Rectangle borderRect = new Rectangle(borderWidth, borderWidth, Width - 2 * borderWidth, Height - 2 * borderWidth);
    Pen p = new Pen(Color.Red, borderWidth);
    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(p, borderRect);
    if (_displayImage != null)
    {
        // Dispose GraphicPath per Jimi comment.
        using (GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath())
        {
            path.AddEllipse(borderRect);
            Region region = new Region(path);
            e.Graphics.Clip = region;
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(_displayImage, borderRect);
            e.Graphics.ResetClip();
        }
    }
    if(_busy.Wait(0))
    {
        try
        {
            DrawExtractedColors(e.Graphics, borderRect);
        }
        finally
        {
            _busy.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**More optimization and thread safety**

While *processing* the full-resolution `_rawImage` file, this `OnPaint` is *showing* a pre-clipped and lower resolution `_displayImage` to save time.

So, suppose you has some kind of `DragDrop` to inject a new image, it might be implemented something like this:

```
SemaphoreSlim _busy = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
protected override async void OnDragDrop(DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (_busy.Wait(0))
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop) is string[] files && files.FirstOrDefault() is string file)
            {
                _rawImage = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(file);
                _displayImage = localResizeImage();
                Invalidate();
                await ExtractUniqueColorsAsync(_rawImage);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Error loading the image: {ex.Message}");
        }
        finally
        {
            _busy.Release();
            Invalidate();
        }
    }
    Bitmap localResizeImage()
    {
        var destRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height);
        var destImage = new Bitmap(Width, Height);
        destImage.SetResolution(_rawImage.HorizontalResolution, _rawImage.VerticalResolution);
        using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(destImage))
        {
            graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
            graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            using (var wrapMode = new ImageAttributes())
            {
                wrapMode.SetWrapMode(WrapMode.TileFlipXY);
                graphics.DrawImage(_rawImage, destRect, 0, 0, _rawImage.Width, _rawImage.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, wrapMode);
            }
        }
        return destImage;
    }
}
private Bitmap? _rawImage = null;
private Bitmap? _displayImage = null;
```

**Update progress bar**

The ~100 progress notifications can be handled like this:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myCustomPicturebox.ProgressChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (!this.IsDisposed) BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                progressBar.Visible = e.ProgressPercentage != 100;
                progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
                progressBar.Invalidate();
            });
        };
    }
}
```